# Find MacOSX version from Python

Tags: python, macos

Currently I am using this:

```
def _get_mac_ver():
    import subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen(['sw_vers', '-productVersion'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    return stdout.strip()
```

Is there a better version (eg: by using built-in Python API)?

```
>>> print _get_mac_ver()
10.6.3
```

Note: I tried `os.uname()[2]` which prints 10.3.0 on a Snow Leopard system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

True to the philosophy that **python comes with batteries included**, there is a module in the standard library to do this: `platform`.

See in particular the [`mac_ver()' function](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#mac-os-platform):

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.mac_ver()
('10.6.3', ('', '', ''), 'i386')
>>> print platform.mac_ver()[0]
10.6.3
```